# Clicking duplicate question: different redirect across sites?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I clicked a question marked as duplicate on [Money.se](https://money.stackexchange.com/):

(Search https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scams, click on the one with title *Tax consequences for moving funds from my U.S. account to wire cash proceeds to U.K.?*)

This immediately brought me to the 'original' [Ghana scam and direct deposit scam?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/76981/ghana-scam-and-direct-deposit-scam).

I then searched on SO for *closed:yes* questions ordered by date, and in the search results click on a dupe, and was NOT redirected.
E.g. [Scroll Android ListView to top without scroll animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42734598/scroll-android-listview-to-top-without-scroll-animation). Instead, it has a link refering to the question it is a dupe off.

Is this different behavior by design?
There are two things that I can think of that are different:

- I deliberately picked a SO question without comments and answers, thinking that maybe you would *not* be redirected if there is something to read under the duplicate. I cannot see if the dupe money question has comments/answers. (Note that I'm actually doing a reverse test here)
- I am *not* a registered user on Money as I am on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not a registered user on Money as I am on SO.

That's it: unregistered users are redirected to the duplicate target, I guess to avoid confusion and be helpful immediately since the visitor doesn't have to click once more. So totally by design if you ask me.

If you are registered, you are more into the network and you will see the actual post you clicked.

Comment: It is by design. Add `noredirect=1` to stay on the [original](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/77164/tax-consequences-for-moving-funds-from-my-u-s-account-to-wire-cash-proceeds-to?noredirect=1)